# Compare and delete similar files

Tags: windows-xp, images, duplicate

I have a hard drive in my laptop plus a second hard drive connected via USB.

I had problems with my hard drives and had to replace some, plus I tried to do selected backups to protect data. I have ended up with a number of image files on both drives, entered under the same name.

I would like to clean this up.

What software do you recommend that will:

- Compare files
- Flag duplicates
- Allow one to delete selected duplicates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Easy Duplicate File Finder**](http://www.easyduplicatefinder.com/download.html) does the job and is my preferred choice.

[image]

There is also [**Auslogics Duplicate File Finder**](http://www.auslogics.com/en/software/duplicate-file-finder/download) and [**Clonespy**](http://www.clonespy.com/?Download). All of these utilities are **freeware**.

Answer (score 0):

[WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) can check differences in folders. Worth a try.

[image: winmerge while comparing 2 folders]